# Dynamically Recreate Include File With SCons

Tags: python, scons

I need to fix a SCons project where an include file is dynamically generated by SCons. I created a simple example that illustrates the problem. The `SConstruct` looks like this:

```
current_time = Command("current_time.h",
                       None,
                       "echo '#define CURRENT_TIME' `date +%H%M` > $TARGET")
test = Program("test", "test.cpp", current_time)
# AlwaysBuild(current_time)
```

with `test.cpp`:

```
include <iostream>
#include "current_time.h"
int main() {
    std::cout << "the time is: " << CURRENT_TIME << std::endl;
}
```

SCons won't rebuild the project when the time changes because it is not magic. One way to get around it is to add `AlwaysBuild(current_time)` to the SCons file.

In the real project, rebuilding the include file with `AlwaysBuild` is rather expensive, and it only needs to rebuild once a day since there is not a time but a date that changes. So, how can I achieve that the file is only regenerated once a day?

**SOLUTION**: I created a function that returns the contents of the generated include file:

```
def include_file_contents():
    ...
    return file_contents  # str
```

I then replaced `None` with `Value(include_file_contents())` in the dependencies:

```
    current_time = Command("current_time.h",
                       Value(include_file_contents()),
                       "echo '#define CURRENT_TIME' `date +%H%M` > $TARGET")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
import time
now=time.strftime("%H:%M",time.localtime())
current_time = Command("current_time.h",
                       Value(now),
                       "echo '#define CURRENT_TIME' %s > $TARGET"%now)
test = Program("test", "test.cpp")
```

You shouldn't have to have current_time.h as a source. SCons will scan the test.cpp and find the included files.

Comment: Your solution works, that is pretty cool. Could you expand your answer to include how it works and maybe the relevant SCons documentation? Additionally, my example is artificial to show what the problem is `in principle`. The real problem is rather complex and includes repository timestamps and such.

Comment: I'd suggest you go look up Value nodes in the users guide and manpage.    Though https://github.com/scons/scons/wiki/BuildNumberProcessing might be what you're actually looking for..